# change color of odd/even DIVs in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

For example we 5 DIVs:

```
<div id="container" >
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

How can I change the background color of even DIVs?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know if it's possible with CSS.  Thanks.

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS3. Pending the much-anticipated release of CSS4, probably about 2 years from now, JS or jQuery will have to do; alternatively, this can be done with PHP and MySQL, although a client-side approach is much simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted a javascript option for some reason (maybe you're looking to do more than just a class?) you could use the each() function in jquery. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pkDkP/2/) is a functioning example to boot!

**CSS**

```
.redBox{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}​
```

**Javascript**

```
var i = 0;
$(".child").each(function(i){
    if(i%2===0){
        $(this).addClass("redBox");
    }
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Seems to work in ie8 using jquery anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282066/ie8-and-jquery-selectors

Comment: Just tested my answer!!! [my jQuery works in IE8 and both CSS3 and jQuery work in IE9](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EFVE7/)

Answer (score 10):

***CSS3*** - not working in older browsers such as IE8

```
#container2 > div:nth-child(even){
  background: yellow;
}
```

***jQuery*** which does work in IE8 too

```
$("#container > div:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
```

I also found this discussion: [IE8 and jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282066/ie8-and-jquery-selectors)

Here is a [DEMO of CSS3 and jQuery both](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EFVE7/)

```js
$("#container1 > div:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
```

```css
.even {
  background-color: yellow
}

#container2>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery:
<div id="container1">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
<hr/> CSS3:
<div id="container2">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know if it's possible with CSS. is nth-child a CSS3 option? Thanks

Comment: Yes. See updated demo. If your target browser show both containers with zebra stripes, then use the CSS one

Answer (score 6):

try `nth-child` **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/SxnsG/)**

```
div:nth-child(even){
background: yellow;
}

div{
 background: red;
}
```

Comment: This is the best implementation, and much neater than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it with CSS?

```
#container child:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use CSS3 nth-child selector. You can find samples on [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)