# CSS pseudo-class fallback?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'd like to use the `tr:nth-child(even/odd)` pseudo class for a table, but I want to support the IE 2 population as well. So, is there any purely css way to add a border to `tr` if `nth-child` isn't supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/), I think that's the easiest solution.

EDIT:

You could also use jquery to add classes for you:

```
$(function() {
    $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("tr:even").addClass("even");
});
```

EDIT2:

Also, if you're using Modernizr, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630408/how-to-test-for-nth-child-using-modernizr).

EDIT3 :)

```
tr { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }

tr:nth-child(odd),
tr:nth-child(even) { border: none; }

tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }

tr:nth-child(even) { background: #ddd; }
```

Comment: I try to avoid scripts, but I suppose if I'm already using jQuery, I might as well try that.

Comment: Yes, I don't think there's a way around it unfortunately. You could try styling your stuff for older browsers first and then you can override it with css3 selectors, does it make sense?

Comment: Do note that when using jQuery to add classes to even or odd elements in IE8, it might not work as intended - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282066/ie8-and-jquery-selectors

Answer (score 0):

You could add `+` between your classes/elements to do like in this example below, every 5 `<tr>` remove the `margin-right`

```
tr{margin-right:10px;}
tr + tr + tr + tr + tr{margin-right:0;}
```

A great replacement for NTH pseudo-classes without any javascript and IE7+ compatible ;)