# Ul and li styling

Tags: css

I have **'ul'** and **'li'** structure elements, i need to apply css to **li** in that manner in which after every 4 **li** elements, 5th **li** should take given css.
i have given margin right : 26px to each li, but i want to give margin right : 0px to 5th element
Below is my Html :

```
 <ul class="clearfix">       
          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/01-turntable-illustration-graphic.png"  title="Turntable by Jens Kappelmann">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/01-turntable-illustration-graphic-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="turntable"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/02-robot-diy-kit.png" title="DIY Robot by Jory Raphael">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/02-robot-diy-kit-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="DIY Robot Kit"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/03-todly-green-monster.png" title="Todly by Scott Wetterschneider">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/03-todly-green-monster-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="Todly"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/04-loz-tea-party.png" title="LoZ Tea Party by Joseph Le">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/04-loz-tea-party-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="legend of zelda tea party"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/05-klaxon-air-horn.png" title="Klaxon Icon by John Khester">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/05-klaxon-air-horn-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="airhorn icon"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/06-flat-coffee.png" title="Flat Coffee by Baglan Dosmagambetov">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/06-flat-coffee-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="flat coffee"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/07-ipad-music-player.png" title="iPad Music Player by Angel Bartolli">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/07-ipad-music-player-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="player ui"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/08-extreme-fish-bowl.png" title="Extreme Fish Bowl by Brian Franco">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/08-extreme-fish-bowl-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="extreme skateboarding fish bowl"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/09-city-building-illustration.png" title="Illustration by Brandon Ancone">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/09-city-building-illustration-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="city illustration"></a></li>

          <li><a href="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/10-big-restaurant.png" title="Restaurant Illustration by Dury">
              <img src="CSR_Js/CSR-PhotoGallery/images/photos/10-big-restaurant-thumbnail.png" width="170" height="150" alt="restaurant illustration"></a></li>

      </ul>
```

Css for this is ;

```
#thumbnails ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/ckggjqne/

Comment: Hey Naeem, But i need to give margin-right:0px to it.

Comment: Please, study some CSS options. [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css)

Comment: @Mardzis: Please help, i have given margin right : 26px to each li, but i want to give margin right : 0px to 5th element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo class, `nth-child` for that purpose , see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/ckggjqne/) .

```
li:nth-child(5n)
{

    color:red;
}
```

but this is **not supported in older browsers**, so the as a fallback you can use a library [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/). also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323591/css-pseudo-class-fallback)

Comment: i have given margin right : 26px to each li, but i want to give margin right : 0px to 5th element.

Answer (score 2):

Use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```
li:nth-child(5n){
  /*style here*/
}
```